# Is there a limit in the number of connections?

Tags: configuration, onion-services, relays, security

When I use Tor as a socks5 proxy for my applications, is there a limit in the number of connections I can perform to other hidden services (addresses.onion)?

I am developing an application to check the online status of a big list of onion hidden services. How many connections should it try simultaneously to be the most efficient?

Comment: _".. online status of a big list of onion hidden services .."_ <-- please have consideration for your Guard.

Comment: True that. But I promise I will use it just once.